# When do stochastic processes increase mutual information?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, information-theory, quantum-information

Suppose we have a composite system that is made up of two random variables $A,B$. And suppose also that the mutual information of the system is non-zero, $I(A;B) > 0$. We then apply a stochastic process $\Pi$ to the entire system, whose joint probability distribution is $p(a,b)$.

For lack of better notation, let's use a dash to indicate the state of the system after $\Pi$, so $p(a',b') = \Pi(p(a,b))$. Let $I(A';B')$ be the mutual information of the system after $\Pi$ has been applied.

Under what conditions on $\Pi$ will we have that $I(A';B') \geq I(A;B)$?

I had wondered perhaps if $\Pi$ does not act independently on the two systems, i.e. in matrix form one cannot write the transition elements of $\Pi$ as $p(a',b'|a,b) = p(a'|a)p(b'|b)$, this might be equivalent to creating/not reducing statistical dependence in the output $p(a',b')$? But I also worry that this is so qualitative there may be easy counter examples that I'm overlooking!

If anyone has any insight or can point me toward resources for this topic I'd be very interested. Thank you for your help!

Comment: What does it mean to apply a stochastic process to a system?

Comment: Right, I mean that the system has a probability distribution which describes it and I am thinking of the stochastic process as a map $\Pi$ which I 'apply' to send a joint probability distribution for $A, B$ to a joint probability distribution for $A', B'$.

Comment: What properties does this map need to satisfy?  If none, it sounds like you are just comparing to different random vectors $(A,B)$ and $(A',B')$. It is kind of like asking if we have two numbers $x$ and $y$, and some function $f$ that satisfies $y=f(x)$, what properties of $f$ do we need to ensure $y\geq x$?  The function $f$ has nothing to do with it, you are just directly comparing $y$ and $x$ to find which is larger.

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify more - the system is finite and the stochastic map should be a discrete memoryless channel which is a row-stochastic matrix (rows sum to 1). You may well be right, I just thought that in the case that the channel acts independently on A and B one could use data-processing twice to show that $I(A',B') \leq I(A,B)$, so I wondered if this had a sort of converse.

Comment: There is a difference between mapping a distribution to another distribution, and mapping a random variable to another random variable.  When you talk about "discrete memoryless" I think you really mean you are mapping a random variable to a random variable.  The "data processing" inequalities of information theory are then relevant here. For example if $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are  deterministic functions then $$I(X;Y)\geq I(X;g(Y)) \geq I(h(X);g(Y))$$ See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_processing_inequality

Comment: The data processing inequality is more general than I have stated but requires some conditional independence properties. Without that, you can always define an arbitrary random vector $(A', B')$ and then consider a trivial map that maps all random vector inputs $(X,Y)$ to the random vector output $(A',B')$ (which may have nothing to do with $(X,Y)$).  So then $(A,B)$ is mapped to another vector $(A',B')$ which has nothing to do with $(A,B)$,  and comparing $I(A;B)$ to $I(A';B')$ is meaningless.